# Absolute path incorrect after website migration

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website I migrated to a new host.

I see that the absolute path is incorrect now. I suspect it is defined somewhere but I cannot figure out where, **it is not in the database**, please don't suggest wp_options solutions, that is not the issue.

See the errors, I have also added some debugging values at the top:

http://d42.e13.myftpupload.com/

The incorrect path is:

```
/home/content/p3nexnas06_data03/60/2186760/html/
```

The correct path is:

```
/home/d42e2186760983/html
```

Both `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and `dirname(__FILE__)` are returning the absolute path to the old server meaning, somewhere a `ROOT_PATH` constant has been set but I have no idea where. It is not in `wp-options.php`, `wp-load.php`, `wp-settings.php` and is obviously a PHP issue, not a Wordpress issue anyways.

Comment: search\grep for the path

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` (recursively) to search for that document:

```
grep -r '$_SERVER' .
```

in the directory (root) of your new server.

Note the single quotes in the command, otherwise `$` can be interpreted as an environment variable.

It is possible that the resuling list is too long, perhaps searches on `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and `__FILE__` will ease checking...

Comment: sorry I am not a PHP guy, I don't know how to run grep, can run grep the same way I can run echo in php file?

Comment: @BrianOgden: This has nothing to do with PHP itself. You run an `ssh` session on your new server and then run `grep` in the terminal/command line.

Comment: Got it, no ssh for this little site with the Godaddy hosting type I got, downloading all files and will search on my box when the all come down, thanks

Comment: @BrianOgden: Really?! I've got a webserver for $8/yr with ssh support. I thought this was a really basic facility...

Comment: Well that is what a GoDaddy rep just said, she wasn't that knowledgeable about it all but its a Managed Wordpress hosting package so perhaps you can't SSH in, I tried and Putty just kept shutting down on login

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you've either...

A) Got an .htaccess that is setting your path.
or
B) Have the document root set in the httpd.conf.

Did you migrate system files as well or only the www folder?

Comment: I only migrated the www, I am using godaddy and don't have access to system files I believe. There was an automatic migration feature and GoDaddy did the migration via a script. There is nothing in the htaccess file setting the path

Comment: In that case, sounds like your best option is searching for that string. Or call godaddy and have them look for you if you don't have access.